# Using percent in jQuery Nested plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying out a rather new mutli-column grid jQuery plugin called Nested (http://suprb.com/apps/nested/) and am not used to setting the size parameters in percentages.

Here is the HTML:

```
            <div id="container">
            <div class="box">1</div> x5
            </div>
```

Now, in the nested.js file,

```
    $.Nested.settings = {
    selector: '.box',
    minWidth: 200,
    minColumns: 1,
    gutter: 1,
    resizeToFit: true, // will resize block bigger than the gap
    resizeToFitOptions: {
        resizeAny: true // will resize any block to fit the gap         
    },
```

I want to change the "minWidth" to a percentage.
In this case, the container which contains `.box` is 100%,
and I want it to always have 5 columns with each equal to at least 20% in width,
so that it fits in the 100%.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I would have thought you want `width` rather than `minWidth`? If all 5 cols are min 20%, then the minimum possible width for them all together is 100%, which means there's no room for them ever to be bigger than 20%.

Comment: Have you tried using `'20%'` -- ie putting the width value in quotes?

Comment: @SDC thanks for replying. Yes, I've tried out using that way of putting in percents, but it causes the script to go crazy, and makes the browser not respond. The reason I'm keeping the "minWidth" is because thats how it was originally, and I though changing it to "width" would result in some even more weird stuff happening.

Comment: `width` is much less likely to do "weird stuff" than `minWidth`. It may even be that minWidth is the cause of the problem with the quoted percent string.

Comment: Thanks. I replaced 'minWidth' with 'width', but I still get a fail in running the script. The confusing part about this plugin is that each '.box' can be assigned with another class called '.size', with 2 digits of numbers following it. So if 'minWidth' was '200', and I place a '.box' with '.11' after it in the HTML, that '.box' is going to be '200' in both width and height. But if it's '.22', it's twice those numbers.

Comment: @SDC and the tutorial on the creator's page only shows options in 'minWidth' which is leading me to think that 'width' can't be used.

Comment: It looks from the plugin API that you can just use 20?  It seems like its naturally in percent.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use css?

```
<style>
 .box{
 width:20% !important;
 }
 </style>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using plugins such as this, because,
one .box may be 20% in width(and also the same height, in pixels), but another .box may be 20%, but may have a different height, and want them to fit together perfectly without margins like in jQuery Masonry or Isotope.

Comment: Well you can set it with css then take the width with Jquery and pass it to nested. Or you can take the parent width and divide by 5 still getting the 20% width.